# How flex custom code generation for components

Tags: apache-flex

- [Flash Builder Design View extension FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/design-view-extensions-faq.html)

  - [Extending Flex Builder](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2008-develop/extending-flex-builder-by-david-zuckerman-and-mike-morearty/)
  - [Design View Extensibility Kit for Flex 4.5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/extensibility/DesignViewExtKitReadme.htm)

I refers the above links, in that they explain that, we can do custom code generation for flex through a Java Extension class and design.xml. I understood about design.xml. but in the case of Extension class where I will get a example. The above links gave me a little idea about the custom code generation. please help me where i will get more details about the custom code generation in flex and flash builder 4.5. please give me a example or your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As I see it there are mainly two types of components.

1. Control (Button, TextInput, TextArea etc)
2. Container (VGroup, HGroup, Accordian etc)
   With control components, you can set the properties and it gets reflected in design view of Flash Builder. Contains on the other hand can have layout logic and can accept drag/drop of other controls/containers. It depends on which kind of component you are trying to develop. In Flash Builder 4.5 you can see DataGrid supports direct connectivity and is more advanced. You can set the dataprovider and map the data to grid columns. For that kind of functionality, you will have to extend the design view extension.